# Python: access nested functions by name

Tags: python, reflection, nested-function

Inside a function, I can use dir() to get a list of nested functions:

```
>>> def outer():
...  def inner(): pass
...  print dir()
...
>>> outer()
['inner']
```

...but then what?  How can I access these functions by name?  I see no `__dict__` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Are you sure you want to do this? It's usually not a good idea. That said,

```
def outer():
    def inner(): pass
    locals()['inner']()
```

You can use `locals` to get a dictionary of local variable values, then look up the value of `'inner'` to get the function. Don't try to edit the local variable dict, though; it won't work right.

---

If you want to access the inner function outside the outer function, you'll need to store it somehow. Local variables don't become function attributes or anything like that; they're discarded when the function exits. You can return the function:

```
def outer():
    def inner(): pass
    return inner

nested_func = outer()
nested_func()
```

Comment: In case you're interested, I want to make a dictionary of handler functions, and want to avoid adding dozens of lines like `handler["foo"] = foo`.  I'd use lambdas if I could...